# Project Quotas in ext4

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4, xfs

This is regarding setting of Project Quotas/ Directory Quotas on ext4 filesystems. The patch for allowing Project Quotas in ext4 filesystems was submitted via patch https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/541895/ .

I have tried the below steps (followed by relevant commands):
1. Create file system on block device 
mkfs.ext4 /dev/nvme0n1

2. Enable Project quota
   tune2fs  -O project -Q prjquota /dev/nvme0n1
3. Mount the block device:
   mount -o prjquota /dev/nvme0n1 /test
4. Enable Quotas on mount path:
   quotaon -Pv -F vfsv1 /test
5. Create the Project ID / Project Name for the Project Quota:
   echo 51:/test/first >> /etc/projects
   echo testproj:51 >> /etc/projid
6. Edit the Quota related to Project user: testproj
   edquota  -P testproj

set the soft block unit to 10, hard unit to 20

7. Conform the Quota is set

repquota -avugP

Report for project quotas on device /dev/nvme0n1
Block grace time: 7days; Inode grace time: 7days
                        Block limits                File limits

### Project         used    soft    hard  grace    used  soft  hard  grace

testproj  --       0      10      20              0     0     0

8. Start writing/ performing IO on said directory under /test/first

fallocate -l 10G ten.txt

9. I can see that a file with size 10G is created at said location, and running the above command in #7 I can see no change in inodes consumed.

Are there any other steps to enable quotas on ext4 file systems?

Kernel Version:4.15.0-36-generic

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are missing a

```
chattr +P -p 51 /test/first
```

/etc/projects seems only used by XFS tools. Also /etc/projid is only there for pretty printing.

fyi this is the procedure I came up with:

(step 0 to actually create the block device:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/fs bs=1024 count=80000
losetup -f /tmp/fs
losetup -l
```

)

1. create a file system with big enough inodes:

```
mkfs.ext4 -I 256 /dev/loop0
```

2. enable project quotas and make sure the file system is mounted with it by default (here using extended options with `-E`, avoiding the mount option in your step3, but also quite sneaky as you don't see it in /proc/mounts as mounted as such)

```
tune2fs -Q prjquota  /dev/loop0
tune2fs -E mount_opts=prjquota /dev/loop0
```

3. mount it

```
mount /dev/loop0 /mnt/loop/
```

4. the quota on command does not seem useful, so skipping this one
5. set a proj id, but as a pure courtesy for the next sys admin logging in to your box. Not actually required

```
echo testproj:51 >> /etc/projid
```

6. actually make your folder part of the project (which was missing from your list)

```
mkdir abc
chattr +P -p 51 abc
```

7. edit the quota. Let's use the setquota tool, that could be used later in some ansible playbook someday, unlike edquota which runs an interactive editor:

```
setquota -P testproj 0 1234 0 0 /mnt/loop/
```

8. confirm the quota is set

```
repquota  -P   /mnt/loop/
# in some parsable format, assuming you wrote some simple enough strings in projid, since the xml formatter is pretty basic
repquota -P /mnt/loop/ -O xml
```

9. verify it works:

as a normal user:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=someoutput oflag=append
loop0: write failed, project block limit reached.
dd: writing to 'someoutput': Disk quota exceeded
2471+0 records in
2470+0 records out
1264640 bytes (1.3 MB, 1.2 MiB) copied, 0.00985608 s, 128 MB/s
```

10. verify you can trivially escape it though, as a normal user:

```
chattr  -p 43 someoutput
dd if=/dev/zero of=someoutput oflag=append
dd: writing to 'someoutput': No space left on device
127427+0 records in
127426+0 records out
65242112 bytes (65 MB, 62 MiB) copied, 0.561987 s, 116 MB/s
```

here completely filling the file system.

EDIT: more info on the limitations of project quotas [Re: Project Quota file owner could change its project ID?](https://lore.kernel.org/linux-ext4/6B0D1F84-0718-4E43-87D4-C8AFC94C0163@dilger.ca/), [Re: ext4 and project quotas bugs (/ features)](https://marc.info/?l=linux-ext4&m=158813125726423&w=2)

Comment: Note that `-I 256` is already the default when using `mkfs.ext4`, so that part of the answer is a bit redundant.

Comment: ```
> mkfs.ext4 /tmp/bar
mke2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
...
> tune2fs -l /tmp/bar  | grep -i inode\ size
Inode size:               128
```
not for very small file systems.