# How to limit "Archive the Artifacts" max size in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, archive

How can we limit Jenkins users to archive a large amount of files/large files in their jobs? It should be something on the Jenkins management level, but we didn't find the way to do so. Is there an option to limit a max size of archived file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way built into Jenkins to do this, but haven't done an exhaustive search.

As a workaround you could try to use separate partitions/volumes or quotas for each jobs directory. I haven't done extensive testing, but Jenkins seems to continue to work after one job hits no space left.

[This answer explains how to use groups and ACLs to make sure files in  directory always get assigned that group.](https://superuser.com/a/381525) [Then you can use group quotas to restrict the space usage for each.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Disk_quota)

[This answer is an example of how to use project quotas which could here be an alternative to group quotas.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61465057/7496656)